# Dynamic font size in CSS

Tags: css

In my website I have a fixed-size rectangle with header. Normally text size is quite big. However, if text is too long it will be truncated. But I'd rather font shrink automatically, like `font-size: size-to-fit`. Is it possible in CSS without JS?

Comment: No, but you could use an SVG image set to `width: 100%`.

Comment: No it's not possbile without javascript and I wouldn't recommend an SVG file because you said you were using it in the header so I am guessing that it is a key word for SEO as well.

Comment: That's not possible just using CSS, you'd need some JS (like [this jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TextFill)) to achieve it.

Comment: CBRRacer, SVG retains text and is therefore visible to search engines. You know I had a reason for recommending SVG.

Comment: @Joey I new it was text based but I thought the text was different than the render hence causing the hidden text black mark, but after a few quick searches I see the light 8-)